# Fatal error: strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in the script in... (PHP7)

Tags: php

Estou estudando PHP e não consigo identificar a causa desse erro:
***"Fatal error: strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in the script in C:\Users\Fernando\OneDrive_Development_Projet\PHP\index.php on line 8"***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Index - PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
    function soma($x, $y){
        $z = $x + $y;
        return $z;
    }   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma força, por gentileza?  :)

Comment: Tenta colocar o `declare(strict_types=1);` como a primeira coisa do arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi, devo definir "declare()" em outro lugar no escopo?

Comment: No mesmo arquivo, na primeira linha: https://pastebin.com/bPfxbGJa

Comment: Mesmo erro, porém aponta para a primeira linha: _**"Fatal error: strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in the script in C:\Users\Fernando\OneDrive\_Development_Projet\PHP\index.php on line 1"_**

Comment: Aqui funcionou. PHP 7.2. Seu arquivo é UTF8? Se sim, ele deve ser sem BOM

Comment: Todavia, como soluciono esse problema?

Comment: Exatamente como eu falei. O arquivo UTF8 não pode ter BOM. No notepad++ tem a opção no menu Formatar para UTF8 sem BOM: https://www.phpbb.com/kb/images/585_encoding.jpg

Comment: Dito e feito, deu certo @lcssanches, muito obrigado!